# How is HTTP an object-oriented protocol?

Tags: oop, http, object, protocols

I have a draft protocol specification on HTTP that is old and may be obsolete, but it says HTTP is: "a generic stateless object-oriented protocol." How is this so? There are many references to an "object" as well, such as: "The content of an object is sent (depending on the method) with the request..." The document: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTTP2.html

Comment: http, like Objects, has methods (get/post/head/search/etc), properties (status, content-lenth), and events (loading, complete, error).

Comment: It is obsolete. Ignore it.